# Node.js React App - exclude packages / node_modules when deploying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, deployment

I have a web app/app service (Linux) hosted on Microsoft Azure. I have Azure tools extensions added to MS Studio Code. I deploy directly from Studio.

- 1 - create a production build
- 2 - update the local GIT repository
- 3 - deploy

Deploying takes 15-20 minutes. While watching the output during deployment I observe that the parts that take up most of the time are creating the zip and copying the code.

At least 95% of the size of my app is packaged. It is my understanding that I do not need to deploy the packages, and that they get added as part of the deployment process.

Can I in fact not deploy the packages? If so, how do I exclude them?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You will certainly need some of your packages, such as React. They include functionality that your app needs to run!

However, some of your dependencies might only be needed during the development or build process. Those aren't needed by end users, and don't need to be included in your development process.

Longer answer: For an app built using node and react, you should be able to modify your `package.json` such that the packages you actually need to run your app are in `dependencies`, while the packages you only need during development are under `devDependencies`.

See this diagram:

[image: Quick prod build explainer]

https://app.eraser.io/workspace/urlFOVr0MxIs7wqo0WZ0?elements=EKdfDYElbLRW6l_FHEl_6w

Exact commands differ depending on whether you are using `yarn` or `npm` (or other) to install things, but you can use e.g. `yarn add --dev` to only add a dev dependency.

Your build tools should generally do this work for you, but exact advice will differ depending on your set up.

Comment: Thanks Joel! It's been a while since my training, I thought that as part of deployment a command gets run (npm start?) that looks at package.json and installs the dependancies?